# Evaluating Expectation of stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expectation

Say, for $u>t$ we have a stochastic process given by :

$$
r_u=r_t + \int_t^u\theta_s ds+\sigma\int_t^udW_s,
$$
where $W_t$ is a brownian motion, $\sigma$ is a constant and $\theta_t$ is some deterministic function.

I have solved for the following:
$$
P(t,T)=\Bbb E[e^{-\int_t^Tr_udu}|\mathscr F_t]=\exp\left(~\frac{\sigma^2}{6}(T-t)^3-\int_t^T(T-s)\theta_sds-r_t(T-t)~\right).
$$

I am trying to evaluate the following expectation though and finding it hard, not really sure how to treat the indicator function:

$$
\Bbb E[e^{-\int_t^Tr_udu}(P(T,S)-K)~ 1_{P(T,S)\ge K}~|\mathscr F_t].
$$
Where K is a constant.
I break this down and get to a point where I need to solve two expectations, one of them is:
$$
\Bbb E[e^{-\int_t^Sr_udu}~ 1_{P(T,S)\ge K}~|\mathscr F_t].
$$

How can I proceed from here? or how can I treat the indicator function?

Comment: @ dinmebucker : hint: the law of $P(T,S)$ is a log normal.

Comment: @TheBridge Could you tell me what the variance of P(T,S) is? I am having trouble deducing that since we know r(T) when calculating P(T,S)

Answer (score 0):

I give you a hint for the calculation of this expression (this doesn't fit into a comment) :

$$\Bbb E[e^{-\int_t^Sr_udu}~ 1_{P(T,S)\ge K}~|\mathscr F_t]$$

First see that $\Bbb E[e^{-\int_t^Sr_udu}~ 1_{P(T,S)\ge K}~|\mathscr F_t]=P(t,S).\Bbb E^S[1_{P(T,S)\ge K}~|\mathscr F_t]=P(t,S).\Bbb P^S(P(T,S)\ge K|\mathscr F_t)$ where $\Bbb E^S$ is the expectation under the S-forward measure.

Now check that the law of $P(T,S)$ under $\Bbb P^S$ is log normal. I leave you the tedious task to determine the mean and variance that will give you the final result.

Best regards

Comment: I am trying to solve it without changing the measure, for example I can express both terms in terms of a standard normal distribution and then make use of the Gaussian Shift Theorem, I'm just not too sure what the distribution of P(T,S) is in this case

Comment: I mean, I know it is normal, just not sure its mean and variance